# Rsync and quotes

Tags: bash, rsync, quotes

I wrote a bash script with the following:

```
SRC="dist_serv:$HOME/www/"
DEST="$HOME/www/"
OPTIONS="--exclude 'file.php'"
rsync -Cavz --delete $OPTIONS $SRC $DEST
```

rsync fails and I can't figure out why, although it seems to be related to the $OPTIONS variable (it works when I remove it). I tried escaping the space with a backslash (among many other things) but that didn't work.
The error message is :

```
rsync: mkdir "/home/xxx/~/public_html/" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I tried quoting the variable, which throws another error ("unknown option" on my variable $OPTIONS):

```
rsync: --exclude 'xxx': unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1422) [client=3.0.6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put `$` in front of the variable names when assigning values to them. `SRC` is a variable, `$SRC` is the value that it expands to.

Additionally, `~` is not expanded to the path of your home directory when you put it in quotes. It is generally better to use `$HOME` in scripts as this variable *behaves like a variable*, which `~` doesn't do.

Always quote variable expansions:

```
rsync -Cavz --delete "$OPTIONS" "$SRC" "$DEST"
```

unless there is some reason not to (there very seldom is). The shell will perform word splitting on them otherwise.

User @Fred points out that you can't use double quotes around `$OPTIONS` (in in comments below), but it should be ok if you use `OPTIONS='--exclude="file.php"'` (note the `=`).

Comment: The OPTIONS variable cannot be quoted, because it contains two words, and quoting will prevent them from being split when interpreting the command (they will be considered as a single string).  In this case, not quoting OPTIONS would work because it does not contain any spaces, but it is not a general solution.

Comment: yes of course re: variable assignment! Editing my question...

Comment: @immicile If you could also mention the exact error message that you get from `rsync` in the question, that would help a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One technique which I find invaluable is using positional parameters to make it easy to work with list of options.

When you put options inside a variable (such as your `OPTIONS` variable), you need to find a way to include quotes inside the value, and omit quotes when referencing the variable.  It works, but you are always one typo away from a difficult to debug failure.

Instead, try the following.

```
set -- -Cavz --delete
set -- "$@" --exclude "file.php"
set -- "$@" "dist_serv:~/www/"
set -- "$@" "~/www/"
rsync "$@"
```

Of course, in this case, everything could be on the same line, but in many cases there will be conditional expressions so that, for instance, you can omit a given option, or select difference files to work with.  The nice thing is, you always use the same quoting you would use on a single command line, all thanks to the magic of `"$@"` that avoids having to reference (or quote) any specific variable.

If actual positional parameters get in the way, you can put them in variables, or create a function to isolate a context that avoids touching them where they matter.

I use this trick all the time, and I have stopped pulling my hair out due to quoting causing problems inside values I pass as parameter to commands.

A similar result can be achieved by using an array.

```
declare -a ARGUMENTS=()
ARGUMENTS=(-Cavz --delete )
ARGUMENTS+=(--exclude "file.php")
ARGUMENTS+=("dist_serv:~/www/")
ARGUMENTS+=("~/www/")
rsync "${ARGUMENTS[@]}"
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround but my script already uses positional parameters and they would get overwritten.

Comment: I have added an array-based solution that produces similar results without using positional parameters.